# Why does Postgres sometimes choose to use parallel workers, and other times not?

Tags: postgresql-performance

The same query generates two different plans, which I've visualized here:

- https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/7076b8f12gd7h63d (uses parallel workers, 30s execution time)
- https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/eagfdg58dea5a19d (does not use parallel workers, < 1ms execution time)

I can't understand why it changes the execution plan like this. I'll run this query many times in a row, and sometimes I'll get MOSTLY fast plans, and other times I'll get MOSTLY slow plans.

I'm also surprised that the parallel plan is slower -- it seems not to use indexes in the same way. Can indexes get locked somehow, by another process, thus forcing the planner to do something different?

The query is below:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, WAL, TIMING, SUMMARY)
    WITH active_job_ids AS (
      SELECT user_jobs.id
        FROM user_jobs
        JOIN task ON user_jobs.id = task.job
       WHERE (user_jobs.schedulable = TRUE OR user_jobs.user_id IS NOT NULL)
         AND task.status NOT IN ('cancelled', 'complete')
       GROUP BY user_jobs.id
    ), tasks_to_group AS (
      SELECT /* omitted simple column names */
        FROM task
        JOIN active_job_ids ON task.job = active_job_ids.id
        LEFT JOIN product_transfer ON task.product_transfer = product_transfer_id
        LEFT JOIN line_items ON product_internal_id = line_items.id
        LEFT JOIN slots ON product_src = slots.container
        LEFT JOIN slot_groups ON slots.groupid = slot_groups.id
       WHERE task.status IN ('new', 'processing', 'complete', 'error')
    )
    SELECT *
      FROM tasks_to_group;
```

Note: I've obfuscated some table names but the structure of the queries and the execution plans are unchanged.

Comment: Compare `Index Only Scan using move_task_active_job_index on task task_1  (cost=0.12..2473.44 rows=200446 width=8) (actual time=0.201..0.237 rows=17 loops=5)` and `Index Only Scan using move_task_active_job_index on task task_1  (cost=0.12..2.34 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.006..0.018 rows=17 loops=1)`; perhaps vacuum can't keep up with the changes sometimes?

Comment: Having said that, you should state your Postgres version and add the complete table and index definitions. Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)